# How can I find (& de-duplicate) combinations of an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, unique

I have a mapping array of objects in Javascript, like so:

```
Mapping_Array = [
    { input1: node_0, input2: node_1 },
    { input1: node_1, input2: node_2 },
    { input1: node_2, input2: node_3 },
    { input1: node_0, input2: node_1 },
    { input1: node_1, input2: node_0 }
];
```

I was able to de-duplicate those that have the same input1 and input2 (such as the first entry and the 4th entry above), but I can't seem to find and remove those that have the *switched* entries (such as the first entry and the last entry above). I've searched but can't find anything on SO that has a similar answer. Has anyone encountered this & found a solution?

EDIT: adding my current function for how I check for duplicates:

```
function check_mapping_array() {
    // De-duplicate the array
    jsonObject = Mapping_Array.map(JSON.stringify);

    uniqueSet = new Set(jsonObject);
    Mapping_Array = Array.from(uniqueSet).map(JSON.parse);
}
```

Comment: Can you also show your current code for how you are checking / removing? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @Tigger, I've added the de-duplication function I have above.

Comment: What data type are the nodes?

Comment: In general, find a canonical representation for your objects, such as inputs being sorted by node id.

Comment: @Bergi, the nodes are all strings.

Comment: In that case, just `if (obj.input1 > obj.input2) obj = { input1: obj.input2, input2: obj.input1 };`

Comment: Do all objects have the same keys, or is a check needed to see that objects have no other keys (that might make a distinction)? And if they have the same keys, should *all* the corresponding values be taken into account, or only those of `input1` and `input2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data type of node is a string or number.
Updated answer:
use both input1 and input2 as key and store index as a value

```
let map = new Map();

let arr = [
  { input1: "node_0", input2: "node_1" },
  { input1: "node_1", input2: "node_2" },
  { input1: "node_2", input2: "node_3" },
  { input1: "node_0", input2: "node_1" },
  { input1: "node_1", input2: "node_0" }
];

map.set(arr[0]["input1"] + "|" + arr[0]["input2"], 0);

for(let i=1; i<arr.length;i++){
  let temp = map.get(arr[i]["input2"] + "|" + arr[i]["input1"]);

  if(temp != undefined){//switch exists
    console.log("current index",i);
    console.log("prev index", temp);
    //now you remove the previous entry as well
  }
  else{
    map.set(arr[i]["input1"] + "|" + arr[i]["input2"], i);
  }
}
```

For other data types you can always use JSON.stringify

Comment: This is really close...where you put `//remove entry at index i`, I replaced that with `arr.splice(i,1);`
However, do you know how to replace the _other_ entry? e.g. the one that is already in arr?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Using it you can access the index of both the entries